# Build a form where radio options come from stored database values

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

Im trying to build a dynamic form that uses questions in the database as the form fields.

In my database, I have a table named questions, with "Question 1" "Question 2" and "Question 3". They are all yes or no questions.

Here is the code the correctly retrieves the info and builds my dynamic form:

```
<?php  require_once 'includes/session.php'; 
include 'includes/functions.php';

$questions = mysqli_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM rules");
?>

<form action="submit.php">
<?php
while($show= mysqli_fetch_array($questions))
{ ?>
 <label id="<?php echo $show['id']; ?>"><?php echo $show['Rule_Name']; ?></label><input name="<?php echo $show['id']; ?>" type="radio" value="Yes">Yes</input><input name="<?php echo $show['id']; ?>" type="radio" value="No">No</input><br>
  <?php  } ?> 
 <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Because all these fields are dynamically generated, how would I structure the submit.php page to store all the values of the submitted form so that I may insert into my database.

Normally I would write my code like this when I know the values:

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
$answer1 = $_POST['question1'];
```

and so forth.

Since the values are unknown (don't know what questions are going to be added in the future) how would I build that to store the values of all the answers?

I spent some time googling, but didnt come across anything noteworthy. It may be my phrasing of the question was off.

Comment: Are you going to have multiple forms?

Comment: @nerdlyist I only plan to use one form. In my form, I want to display all questions stored in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to build a really dynamic system, you need to use the potential of the database. MySQL is a *relational* database for a reason.

Please do *not* store new questions as columns, but one per row. So, instead of having a questionnaire table like this

```
Questionnaire ID | Question 1 | Question 2 | ... | Question X
```

create two tables, one for the questionnaires:

```
Questionnaire ID | Questionnaire name | Description
```

and another one for the questions:

```
Questionnaire ID | Question Order/ID | Question text | Question options
```

That way, you can easily add new questions to any questionnaire without the need to alter the database schema. Further, you can use a similar setup for the answers:

```
Questionnaire ID | Question ID | User ID | Answer | Timestamp
```

Again, this table schema allows you to save individual answers without the need to alter the table schema when you add new questions.

To actually show a question form (aka load all required questions), you just query the questions table with the respective questionnaire ID, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE questionnaire_id = 1 ORDER BY question_id ASC;
```

This will return all questions of your first questionnaire in the pre-defined order.

**UPDATE**

If you use tables similar to the ones I proposed above, storing the answers is fairly easy. First, add a hidden field to your form which stores the questionnaire ID, e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="questionnaire_id" value="1" />
```

Next, add your questions just like you do already:

```
<input name="<?php echo $show['id']; ?>" type="radio" value="Yes">Yes</input>
```

Eventually - to avoid ambiguous form field names - you can add the letter "q" in front of the name, so instead of having `name="1"` for the first question, you would get something like `name="q1"`.

In your submit handler, just cycle through the POST vars:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
    if (substr($key, 0, 1) == "q") {
        // Remember the added "q"?
        // So, it's an answer to a question!
        $save_answer = array(
            'questionnaire_id' => (int) $_POST['questionnaire_id'], // the hidden form element
            'question_id' => substr($key, 1),
            'answer' => (in_array((string) $val, array('Yes', 'No')) ? (string) $val : null),
            'user_id' => [...], // your logic here
            'timestamp' => time(),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Working on setting this up right now. Will report back when finished.

Comment: I have successfully created the form where it will add all questions from the database. I have the php I wrote for it, but don't think I can display it here in the comment box. I build insert statements all the time for static forms, but how would I accomplish that with this where Im always adding fields. (I did create all three database tables, I now just need to build the input script). Would you like me to edit my question and insert the php into it?

Comment: Yes, update your question for chunks of code. Also specify your question and your intention. Currently, your question is about getting radio options from a database, but in your description you write that all question are yes/no ones.

Comment: I updated my question to include the code block I wrote. This code block successfully connects to my database and lists all my questions. I also reworded my question to ask how I would build the variables on the submit.php page where the values are not hardcoded in.

Comment: Updated my answer as well. It contains some assistance with creating an array for each answer which could then be saved in the database.

Comment: Sorry to ask this. I usually don't have a problem with my insert statements, however, in your example above, where would I run the mysqli_query insert statement?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited your answer at the bottom where it looped through the $_POST to show my revision I made. I appreciate your help!